# Why I'm getting error if i use for loop inside if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I want to run this loop But it is giving me syntax error. Why is it wrong?

```
l = [1,2,3,45,5,6,177,9,8];
i = 0;
if l[i] < l[for j in range(1,9)]:
    i=i+1
```

I have a list l which i want to iterate.
is there any other way to run a loop like this?

Error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-12-c82841ff4cef>", line 3
    if l[i] < l[for j in range(1,9)]:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this syntax to *do*?

Comment: "Why is it wrong?" -- it isn't even close to being valid syntax. It isn't clear what the intention behind `l[for j in range(1,9)]` even is or why you would think python code works like that. It might help if you explain what your loop and what your `if` is trying to do.

Comment: Can you put in words what you want this part: `l[for j in range(1,9)]` to do? It does not make sense to me...

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to find the smallest element and increment it by 1?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I strongly suspect you want either `any` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or `all` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use for loop inside the if statement.
**this is the correct syntax for what you want to do:**

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 45, 5, 6, 177, 9, 8]
i = 0

for j in range(1, 9):
    if l[i] < l[j]:
        i = i+1
```